# Is there any benifit to using a PHP class to handle MySQL queries?

Tags: php, database, mysql

I know several frameworks have this functionality built in where you can use their special methods to make DB queries. I also know this is (partially) to ensure that everything is handled correctly to avoid breaking things. So here is the question, if one not using a framework, is there sufficient benefit to using a class like that rather then typing out SQL by hand where needed? Consider the following code.

---

```
/* What the method might look like and it's call */

$db->('little_bobby', array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 1337));

public function insert($table, $values)
{
  $cols = [];
  $vals = [];
  foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
    $cols[] = $column;
    $vals[] = $value;
  }
  $columns = implode(',', $cols);
  $bind_labels = ':'.implode(',:', $cols);

  $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES ({$bind_labels})";

  $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query); //$dbc is the connection object

  foreach ($values as $column => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue(":$column", $value);
  }

  return $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

```
/* As opposed to what it would look like by hand */

  $query = 'INSERT INTO little_bobby (foo, baz) 
                   VALUES (:foo, :baz)';
  $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query); //$dbc is the connection object
  $stmt->bindValue(':foo', 'bar');
  $stmt->bindValue(':baz', 1337);

  $result = $stmt->execute();
```

---

Please ignore any syntactical errors unless they prevent understanding of what I'm trying to get at here. Note that I'm not asking if one should use classes to organize code, but rather if devoting a class to constructing and executing DB queries is better than writing out a query by hand.

Comment: Would you consider "ensuring that everything is handled correctly to avoid breaking things" a sufficiently-compelling benefit?

Comment: Well sure. But many of those things are easily done without using a class if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SQL Injections

In your first example, you open a door to SQL Injections. This may happen this way:

1. You'll use `insert($table, $values)` all over the code base. Great.
2. Another developer would follow your example.
3. One day, he will need to insert a value in a dynamically chosen table (for instance through a map of user's input). If he was writing a direct SQL query, he would think twice about the risks and probably select a different approach. But here, he's using a method he trusts and maybe believes to be reliable. After all, why wouldn't *your* method do the sanitization? More importantly, it is very, very easy to use a dynamic name for a table.
4. Later on, someone will notice that the user's input is correlated with the actual value of the variable passed as a first parameter to `insert` method. So why not assigning the value directly from the input instead of using a map? And now, a hacker can do whatever he wants with your database.

### Flexibility

In your first example, you can `INSERT INTO`. Nothing more. No `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. No partitions. Actually, you can't even do `DEFAULT` for the values.

In your second example, imagination is your only limit. The query can be modified with ease, and the change is scoped to one or a few lines of code.

### Readability

In your first example, I has to walk through thirteen lines of code just to understand a basic insertion. Why all this complexity? When you'll start implementing `DEFAULT`s and partitions and all other stuff, it will end up with hundreds and hundreds of lines.

In your second example, the code is right there. A few straightforward statements is all I need to read.

### Maintainability

Sooner or later, you'll end up with queries which take too much time. You'll identify them, and will need to optimize either the database, or the queries.

If you have your queries directly in code, you'll be able to simply `grep` them most of the time (especially since the SQL profiler handles parametrized queries; the one for SQL Server does, don't know about others).

If you have an ORM, chances are it has its own logging mechanism, which will list the problematic query and show the corresponding stack trace.

If you have a layer of abstraction like the one in your question, things could get messy.

### Conclusion

If you don't want to write SQL queries by hand, use an ORM. If you want to write SQL queries by hand, but don't want to type repetititive code, use an object mapper. Just don't reinvent the wheel, and **don't add unnecessary complexity**.